# Root Mean Square Displacement of Diffusion and Radial Diffusion Function

Tags: fluid-dynamics, statistical-mechanics, computational-physics, diffusion

I read, that for normal diffusion the root mean square displacement $\sqrt{\langle x^2(t)\rangle}$ (for particles at the origin) can be interpreted as the mean distance the particles have with respect to the origin at time $t$. For normal diffusion, the MSD is $$\langle x^2\rangle=2Dt$$ and therefore the RMSD equals $$\sqrt{\langle x^2\rangle}=\sqrt{2Dt}.$$ But if I say, this is more or less the expectation value of the origin-to-endpoint distance of a particle diffusing, couldn't I just compute it with a "radialized" diffusion function. That is, with the original diffusion function $$p(\vec{X})=\frac{1}{(4\pi Dt)^{\frac{d}{2}}}\mathrm{e}^{\,-\lVert \vec{X}\rVert^2/4Dt}$$ and transforming this: $$\iiint_{\mathbb{R}^d}d^dX\,p(\vec{X})=\int d\Omega_d\int_0^\infty dR\,R^{d-1}p(R)$$ $$\Rightarrow\ p(R)=S_d\frac{R^{d-1}}{(4\pi Dt)^{\frac{d}{2}}}\mathrm{e}^{\,-R^2/4Dt}$$ where $S_d$ is the surface of the $d$ dimensional unit sphere. Computing $\langle R\rangle$ has the same meaning then as RMSD: **$\boldsymbol{\langle R\rangle}$ and RMSD are both the expected distance from the origin of a particle diffusion at time $t$**. But if I compute $\langle R\rangle$ e.g. in one dimension I get $$\langle R\rangle=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\sqrt{Dt},$$ both are proportional to $\sqrt{t}$ but the constants are different. Is my understanding of the RMSD not right or is there a deeper meaning, e.g. both are under the respective conditions the mean distance to the origin?

Comment: Should the exponents have a negative sign?

Comment: Can you explain more about your "transformation" and how $\langle R\rangle$ is the same thing as a RMSD? I don't follow, and that is probably where your mistake is. Looking at your exponent it just looks like $R^2=||x||^2$. Computing $\langle x^2\rangle$ directly from $p(x)$ works out fine. This question is dangerously close to turning into a "check-my-work" question. I would recommend instead asking about your reasoning as to why $\langle R\rangle$ is a RMSD.

Comment: My reasoning for why $\langle R\rangle$ should be the same as RMSD is that both say something about the expected displacement of particles under diffusion, but obviously they are not equal. Now my question is what the differences could be.

Comment: Shouldn't your integral of $xp(x)$ over all space be $0$? I am also still not following why $\langle R\rangle$ should be the same thing as the RMSD. The RMSD is not an expected distance. It is the square root of the mean of the expected squared distance.

Comment: I got told, RMSD essentially is the mean displacement, so to say $\sqrt{\langle x^2\rangle}\approx\langle\lvert x\rvert\rangle$. Further $\langle\lvert x\rvert\rangle$ with $p(x)$ yields the same result as $\langle R\rangle$ with $p(R)$.

Comment: Ok, I got it. $\langle R\rangle$ is the right way to express the expected distance between the origin and a particle under diffusion, and the RMSD carries the same meaning but not the exact same. Also RMSD is more accessible by experiments that $\langle R\rangle$.

Comment: Sorry but I do not see how you got that expression for $p(R)$. If I am correct in believing that you are defining $R$ as $R^2=\sum_{i=1}^d x_i^2$, then your probability distribution does not change since $R^2 = ||\vec{X}||^2$. Also we can see that the function $p(R)$ is not unitless, so it's probably not correct.

Comment: The probability is rather a probability density; at least some probability densities I know from statistical mechanics had units. Also I think you can't just replace the variable, how would you then integrate the density?